# Previewing React-Native CLI on ios virtually

Tags: ios, react-native, command-line-interface

so i'm making React Native Apps on windows and previewing it on vyser for android. I don't have a mac or Ios. Is there any solution for seeing my app on ios as i build.

i tried a bunch of Web Apps but they doesnt support real time Viewing that is writing lines of code and seeing result on website. Whereas downloading Mac OS virtually is too hard for my PC.

PS- I'm using React-Native CLI

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Snack Expo - React Native in the browser](https://snack.expo.dev)

It lets you organize your React Native project files just like you would locally on your computer. There are options to **'Import files'** & **'Import git repository'**. You will get real time changes and if you complete the coding, you can export your Snack. You can also create an Expo account and save your Snacks to keep working on them or to share them with others.